# problem executing plink(putty) command

Tags: putty, plink

I am using Plink to execute remote command:

When using this from cmd prompt in single line it doesnot work:

```
C:\>c:\plink.exe -l userId -pw psw -m C:\goto\test.bat remote_host
```

It says unable to open command file "C:\goto\test.bat"

But The following works:

```
C:\>c:\plink.exe -l userId -pw psw remote_host
C:\>C:\goto\test.bat
```

Please help.

Comment: Does that use SSH protocol? Do you have an SSH server running on that windows?

Comment: Isn't this a superuser.com question?

Comment: @jlafay: I think so, but it doesn't seem like it's possible to vote to "close" it since it has a bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it like this:

```
c:\plink.exe -l userId -pw psw remote_host C:\goto\test.bat
```

Comment: goto is the path of the bat located remotely.

Comment: So you're saying that C:\goto\test.bat is on the remote machine? If so, you need to run: `c:\plink.exe -l userId -pw psw remote_host C:\goto\test.bat`. The -m flag is for plink to read remote commands from a local file.

Comment: you should edit your answer to include the final solution from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [some documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html), this should work:

```
C:\>c:\plink.exe -l userId -pw psw remote_host C:\goto\test.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

**This has worked for me:**

```
Call \\LocalServerName\plink.exe -pw PASSWORD -m D:\FOLDER\FILE.exe USER@REMOTESERVER
```

**Or if its a local computer:**

```
Call c:\Folder\plink.exe -pw PASSWORD -m D:\FOLDER\FILE.exe USER@REMOTESERVER
```

**Caps - Change it to your state**